# Can't open PDF's in Outlook using Parallels 8 vm

Tags: ms-office, windows, pdf, parallels-desktop

All of the sudden, I am not able to open PDF's that are attached to emails, UNLESS I save/copy them to different location.

Once I save it/copy it or drag it from the email to my OSX 10.8.5 Desktop, I can open it.

I run Win 7 on an MBA w/10.8.5 running in a Parallels vm.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue. I needed to re-associate PDF's w/Adobe in the Win 7 Control panel.